# how to change bottom constraint of a view from safe area to superview programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a view that the bottom is constrained to the safe area like this

[image]

I need to change it to be constrained to superview programmatically.

I don't know what to do to that constraint reference

```
 @IBOutlet var sheetViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Comment: You mean do replace this constraint with the programmatic approach right?

Comment: Why do you have to change the constraint programmatically? Can't you set it to the superview in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, it only requires you to change the item can be done with few clicks.

Comment: @vacawama the view controller above will be used over other view controllers.  I need to constraint it to the safe area (if the tab bar is available, for root view controller in navigation stack), but for other view controller that the tab bar is hidden (in top of navigation stack), I need to constraint it to the superview, it looks weird if I contraint it to safe area, thats why I need to change it programmatically. I am lazy if I make two separate views. I will try frankenstain answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the constraint on story-board and give the constraint via code like this:

```swift
sheetView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Note: To change the constraint programmatically you don't need the `@IBOutlet`

Comment: why not add this constraint on story-board?

Comment: Lol, you should ask this to the person who put the question.